# Cannot find module "cx_freeze__init__" when freezing Python script

Tags: python, exe, freeze, init, cx-freeze

So I am trying to freeze a Python script as an .exe. I installed cx_freeze to do so as I am using 3.4. I created the setup.py file successfully and also ran the build which appears in the build folder and .exe appears. However, when I open the .exe it displays the following error:

```
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't find module 'cx_Freeze__init__'
Fatal python error: unable to locate initialization module

Current thread 0x00001d58 <most recent call first>:
```

I believe I did everything else correctly. There is indeed a cx_Freeze_*init*_.pyc file in the library.zip, however it cannot find it for some reason. The only other error I had was that certain modules were missing when during the cmd build:

```
Missing modules:
? _dummy_threading imported from dummy_threading
? ce imported from os
? doctest imported from heapq
? getopt imported from base64, quopri
? org.python.core imported from copy
? os.path imported from os
? posix imported from os
? pwd imported from posixpath
? subprocess imported from os
This is not necessarily a problem - the modules may not be needed on this platfo
rm.
```

This is the setup.py I used:

```
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
buildOptions = dict(packages = [], excludes = [])

base = 'Console'

executables = [
Executable('guess.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='Guess',
  version = '1.0',
  description = 'test',
  options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
  executables = executables)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure? I installed it from the official cx_freeze site, and it has a version for 3.4. http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Ok I see. It worked when I use 3.3 so I believe you're correct. Wondering if anyone got it to work on 3.4.